# how i can disable cakephp Test Suite?

Tags: cakephp, test-suite

do you test this url in your application that writted with cakephp ?

> www.yourCakephpApp.com/test

you see a page like this:

> http://www.eliteprojects.org/cake/app/webroot/test.php

how i can disable test suite?

Comment: Never happens. Is that your `htaccess` or `mod_rewrite` is not functioning properly? I visited your eliteprojects.org and clearly it's clearly your IIS is not configured correctly to accepts htaccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access CakePHP's built-in test suite's web runner by going to `/yourapp/test.php` or `/test.php`, depending on your server's configuration. Going to `/test` should give you a 404 error unless you specifically added such a route or a file/path named `test` in your `webroot` directory.

You can disable the web runner by denying access to it in your server configurations or by simply removing the file. However, there's rarely a reason to do this, as:

1. A major part of CakePHP's development platform is its comprehensive testing support. It would be like using CakePHP and removing the bake console.
2. The test runner is designed to be accessible only during development. So unless you're using a debug mode > 0 in production (which you shouldn't be doing), the web runner won't be accessible from that URL.

Lastly, if you're new to Cake, **you need to read the [Cake cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contents.html)**. Start from the first section, and work your way down to the Blog Tutorial. This will answer most of your questions and avoid a lot of common mistakes (such as your misconfiguring your server's docroot and not having URL rewriting set up properly).

*Note:
I've bolded the part about the Cookbook because it is such a crucial resource for learning Cake development, and it's the first place you should consult if you run into any problems or have a question. In fact, people get quite annoyed on #cakephp at new users asking the same basic questions that are already answered in the Cookbook—especially if you haven't done the Blog Tutorial.*

Answer (score 3):

It should never happens.

After visiting your main web page, it looks like you are running IIS and your server is misconfigured to run CakePHP project. Cake needs mod_rewrite to work but the `htaccess` is for Apache server only.

While I'm not very sure how to do this, CakePHP documentation did tell you how to achieve this. Checkout the book here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you comment out the contents of test.php and add header("Location: index.php");

??

Comment: do you mean in cakephp i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete `app/webroot/test.php` in your production environment.